# Rsync files-from trouble

Tags: linux, backup, bash, scripting, rsync

I have strange rsync behaviour.
I need to copy all files youngest than 2 days from one folder to another.

So i've mixed rsync with files-from argument and find utility in a script to do what i need to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/smb/online/
find . -mtime -2 -print > /tmp/rsynclist
rsync -av --ignore-existing --size-only --files-from=/tmp/rsynclist /mnt/smb/online /mnt/backup/
```

File /tmp/rsynclist is ok, and have only files that i need (all files not older than 2 days). But rsync seems to ignore that 'files-from' argument and continuing to copy all files from source older.

Where i am mistaking?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the `rsync` command, but in your `find`. While testing your script I noticed that there are also directories in my `rsynclist`file that have been changed, resulting in rsync copying all files under these directories.

To prevent this, add `-type f` to your `find` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/smb/online/
find . -type f -mtime -2 -print > /tmp/rsynclist
rsync -av --ignore-existing --size-only --files-from=/tmp/rsynclist /mnt/smb/online /mnt/backup/
```

Afterwards only paths to files should be in the list, giving in the intended result.

Answer (score -2):

The syntaxe of the `rsync` command is :

```
rsync [option] source[x] destination
```

You had put 2 sources :

- */tmp/rsynclist*  ; the right one
- */mnt/smb/online* ; this is wrong and you must delete it

try with :

```
rsync -av --ignore-existing --size-only --files-from=/tmp/rsynclist  /mnt/backup/
```

Comment: This will in rsync complaining that a parameter is missing.

Comment: files-from is not source folder, it just list of files that rsync need to copy. So source parameter will be missing.